# Iterate over csv file and query on property values - Cypher Neo4j

Tags: loops, csv, filter, neo4j, cypher

Please see the image of the csv file. I am working with Cypher, Neo4j. As you can see the activities with their timestamp all belong to a case_id respectively. Many belong to the same case_id (here you see case_id 3, 2, 1), but please imagine there are many many more. I want to group the activities that belong to the same case id and perform the same! query on each of the groups (the grouping is essential).

Is there a way to do that other than rewriting the same query for each group, as done here in three steps?:

1.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///XY" AS row

WITH toInteger(row.case_id) AS cid, row

WHERE cid=3

CREATE (act:Activity {caseId: cid, activityName: row.activity, time: row.timestamp})

'QUERY'
```

2.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///XY" AS row

WITH toInteger(row.case_id) AS cid, row

WHERE cid=2

CREATE (act:Activity {caseId: cid, activityName: row.activity, time: row.timestamp})

'QUERY'
```

3.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///XY" AS row

WITH toInteger(row.case_id) AS cid, row

WHERE cid=1

CREATE (act:Activity {caseId: cid, activityName: row.activity, time: 
row.timestamp})

'QUERY'
```

So basically I want to generalize `WHERE cid=3(or 2 or 1)` in the sense of iterating over all different case-ids without explicitly naming them. A bit like in Java `for each element in array (array content: group by case_id) do QUERY`.

Any idea how?

Thank you in advance and I will be happy to provide a better description if this sounds too cryptic.

Update: 
Here is the query:

```
MATCH(act: Activity)
WHERE act.caseId = 1 //and here I want to be able to simplify for EVERY caseId
WITH act ORDER BY act.time ASC 
WITH apoc.coll.frequencies(apoc.coll.pairsMin(COLLECT(act.activityName))) AS g
UNWIND g AS p
RETURN*
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that a single LOAD CSV query ought to handle this, just set the caseId to the integer value of row.case_id:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///XY" AS row
WITH toInteger(row.case_id) AS cid, row
CREATE (act:Activity {caseId: cid, activityName: row.activity, time: row.timestamp})
```

Okay, I see you want to execute some query with each group. Can you explain why executing the query after the create in the load csv won't work?

Would performing the query post-import work for you?

Some more information on the query you intend to run would be helpful.

Comment: "Can you explain why executing the query after the create in the load csv won't work?" -> It works, but please imagine there are up to a hundred of different case_ids.                                                                                                               "Would performing the query post-import work for you?" Ideally upon import. But if not possible yes.

Comment: "Some more information on the query you intend to run would be helpful." -> In each group I want to order the nodes via first timestamp and then via pairs of activities.

Comment: Any chance you could provide the query? The `time` property means you just need to query and order by that property, unless you want to create a linked list structure through these nodes in order. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "pairs of activities"?

Comment: Thank you so far InverseFalcon. Actually all I really want to do is perform a query without having to reference every different cid. I had already tried the query you suggested. It imports all the nodes but that is all. But I want a general statement 'for every different cid perform QUERY X'. I can find nothing in manuals etc. I am unable to explain it better at the moment. Maybe someone know what I mean?

Comment: In that case, would it be worth MERGEing a :Case node with the caseId, then doing a CREATE of a relationship between that and the :Activity node? That coupled with a unique constraint on :Case(caseId) would ensure you had a distinct node for every case, then your subsequent query could MATCH on all :Case nodes and perform the query you want (potentially matching to associated :Activity nodes per case)

Comment: Thank you very so far, I need time before I can answer.